# How to change this weird "Heading" tab into default state in the Navigation Pane?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-365

Recently I converted PDF to Word document. After opening this
Word document in MS Word 365, I noticed changes in the "Heading" tab in the left panel:

[image]

I want to change this "Heading" tab into **default**, like this:

[image]

I tried to delete each heading like this:

[image]

But content in the Word document is also getting deleted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Delete the heading or change it to a non-outline level

This change is made in the document body, not in the Navigation Pane.

What you are showing is the Navigation Pane with one heading in the document. This is how it is supposed to look.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my [page on using the Navigation Pane](https://www.addbalance.com/word/navigation2010.htm#start) if you need more information. Also [Outlining Using the Navigation Pane](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm#Big_Idea_5), [The Relationship Between Built-In Headings and the Navigation Pane](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Navigation_Pane), and [Headings That Do Not Show Up in the Navigation Pane or Table of Contents](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/headings-that-do-not-show-up-in-the-navigation/1d3bdc6d-218b-4b90-8e58-f1e0530f75bd).

**Documents converted into Word almost always have strange formatting that may not be visible to the naked eye or in a printed document.** Here is my writing on [examining such formatting](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#RevealCodes).